# VS2010 - How to quickly rename a newly created interface control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, rename

When I create a new label, button, text box, etc. in Visual Studio the first thing I want to do is rename it from "textbox1" to "tbxDestination" or something useful.  This involves moving over to the Properties window, possibly scrolling up to the Name Field, double-clicking, and typing in my new name.

When the control is created, it is still selected.  Is there a function key or hotkey that will allow me to rename it immediately after creating it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ctrl + R,R 
Ctrl + R, Ctrl + R
```

are both shortcuts to rename in VS2010.

Comment: This shortcut works for renaming a variable within source code but is not functional when using the UI editor.